# How to reinstall rvm nicely on ubuntu 12.04 which has rails/passenger/nginx running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

There are a few posts about how to remove the `rvm`. What we want to do is to `reinstall the rvm` on `ubuntu` which already has `rails passenger/nginx` installed. Under the `ruby 2.0.0` in .rvm subdirectory, there are gems installed for our `rails 3.2.12` application. Is there a way we can `reinstall rvm` without reinstalling `passenger/nginx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the .rvm folder from your home folder

and follow [these](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) instructions for installation

Comment: There are passenger/nginx/rails working on the server now. After reinstalling of rvm, do you think we need to reinstall the passenger/nginx again?

Comment: You need to install passenger gem, but i dont think u hav to install nginx again.